# Extracting texts and anchors values from the tables using jsoup

Tags: java, ws4j

Actually, I need to extract the text data and anchors values (link text and URL from ahref) from all the tables for semantic similarity measurments using ws4j. The measurements are required to obtain from webpage with following address:
http://ws4jdemo.appspot.com/?mode=s&s1=Eventually%2C+a+huge+cyclone+hit+the+entrance+of+my+house.&s2=Finally%2C+a+massive+hurricane+attacked+my+home.

Any help in this matter would be appreciated.

Comment: This question does not contain any information of what you have already tried to solve the problem. The question you ask seems to be doable with JSoup though.

Comment: Your question is too broad. What have you tried? Where did you have problems? Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: As you have not mention what you have done so far. Following might be a starting point [jsoup table](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[jsoup]+table), [jsoup anchor](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[jsoup]+anchor), [jsoup text](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[jsoup]+text)